# How to open a HTML file in a non-default file type application(browser) using python?

Tags: python-3.x

Does anyone know how to open a HTML file in a browser that isn't the default HTML file type browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code

```
webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open("file/path/name.html")
```